# TFS 2013: Publish clickonce application from TFS build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

Is there any UPDATED guides to how to do this? I can only find stuff from 2010 which **DOES NOT WORK** with 2013.

I'm trying to set up a build so when it's ran it automatically publishes the clickonce application. I did find this article, and it was SOMEWHAT working (http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/05/continuous-integration-with-tfs-and.html), but I could not for the life of me get the version updating part working, so I scrapped it.

I'm currently using the default TfvcTemplate.12.xaml and I really don't know how it fully works. I'm a novice here and could use a nudge into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guide published 4 days ago...

Build and Publish a ClickOnce App using Team Build/VSO
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2015/09/15/build-and-publish-a-clickonce-app-using-team-build-vso.aspx